# How to Merge or make UpdateorInsert in JPA Spring Boot

Tags: java, jsp, jpa, spring-boot

My Problem is that i can not update or Insert the Record that already exist.

i have this methode for update or Insert new Record in my CompanyService

```
public void save(Company company) {

    companyRepository.save(company);
}
```

That is my Company Repository

```
public interface CompanyRepository extends CrudRepository<Company, Integer>
```

so is my Controller to save the Company Entity

```
@PostMapping("/save-company")
    public String saveTask(@ModelAttribute Company company, BindingResult bindingResult, HttpServletRequest request) {

        companyservice.save(company);
        return "createcompagny";
    }
```

That is my Company Table
[image]

When i try to create new Record it Works fine. But i can not update new Record.

The complete Company Entity

```
@Entity
public class Company {

    private long companyId;

    private String companyName;
    private String website;
    private String about;
    private String city;
    private int location;
    private int industryid;
    private int userid;

    /**
     * @return the userid
     */
    public int getUserid() {
        return userid;
    }

    /**
     * @param userid the userid to set
     */
    public void setUserid(int userid) {
        this.userid = userid;
    }

    private int numbere;

    private Industry industry;
    private Countries countries;
    private CompanySize companysize;
    private User user; 

    /**
     * @return the user
     */
    @OneToOne(optional=false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userid",insertable=false,updatable=false) 
    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    /**
     * @param user the user to set
     */
    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    private Set<Job> job;

    /**
     * @return the job
     */
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company", targetEntity = Job.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Set<Job> getJob() {
        return job;
    }

    /**
     * @param job the job to set
     */
    public void setJob(Set<Job> job) {
        this.job = job;
    }

    /**
     * @return the companysize
     */
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "numbere", referencedColumnName = "id",insertable=false,updatable=false)
    public CompanySize getCompanysize() {
        return companysize;
    }

    /**
     * @param companysize the companysize to set
     */
    public void setCompanysize(CompanySize companysize) {
        this.companysize = companysize;
    }

    /**
     * @return the countries
     */

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "location", referencedColumnName = "id",insertable=false,updatable=false)
    public Countries getCountries() {
        return countries;
    }

    /**
     * @param countries the countries to set
     */
    public void setCountries(Countries countries) {
        this.countries = countries;
    }

    /**
     * @return the industryid
     */
    public int getIndustryid() {
        return industryid;
    }

    /**
     * @param industryid the industryid to set
     */
    public void setIndustryid(int industryid) {
        this.industryid = industryid;
    }



    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public long getCompanyId() {
        return companyId;
    }

    /**
     * @param id
     *            the id to set
     */
    public void setCompanyId(long id) {
        this.companyId = id;
    }

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getCompanyName() {
        return companyName;
    }

    /**
     * @param name
     *            the name to set
     */
    public void setCompanyName(String name) {
        this.companyName = name;
    }

    /**
     * @return the website
     */
    public String getWebsite() {
        return website;
    }

    /**
     * @param website
     *            the website to set
     */
    public void setWebsite(String website) {
        this.website = website;
    }

    /**
     * @return the about
     */
    public String getAbout() {
        return about;
    }

    /**
     * @param about
     *            the about to set
     */
    public void setAbout(String about) {
        this.about = about;
    }

    /**
     * @return the city
     */
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    /**
     * @param city
     *            the city to set
     */
    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }



    /**
     * @param location
     *            the location to set
     */
    public void setLocation(int location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    /**
     * @return the industry_id
     */
    public int getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    /**
     * @param industry_id
     *            the industry_id to set
     */

    /**
     * @return the numbere
     */
    public int getNumbere() {
        return numbere;
    }

    /**
     * @param numbere
     *            the numbere to set
     */
    public void setNumbere(int numbere) {
        this.numbere = numbere;
    }

    /**
     * @return the industry
     */
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "industryid", referencedColumnName = "id",insertable=false,updatable=false)
    public Industry getIndustry() {
        return industry;
    }

    /**
     * @param industry
     *            the industry to set
     */
    public void setIndustry(Industry industry) {
        this.industry = industry;
    }

    // private byte[] logo;

}
```

Complett User Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String passwordConfirm;
    private Set<Role> roles;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Transient
    public String getPasswordConfirm() {
        return passwordConfirm;
    }

    public void setPasswordConfirm(String passwordConfirm) {
        this.passwordConfirm = passwordConfirm;
    }

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }
}
```

JSP PAGE

```
<form method="POST" action="save-company">
<c:forEach var="user" items="${users}">
<c:if test="${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name == user.username}">
<div class="row">
    <div class="six columns">
      <label for="usernameInput">Email Adresse</label>
      <input class="u-full-width" type="text" placeholder="Email Adresse" id="usernameInput" name="username"  value="${user.username}">
      <input type="text" name="userid" value="${user.id}" />
    </div>
  </div>
  </c:if>
</c:forEach>




  <div class="row">
    <div class="six columns">
      <label for="compnaneInput">Company Name</label>
      <input class="u-full-width" type="text" placeholder="Company Name" id="compnaneInput" name="companyName"  value="${company.companyName}">
    </div>
    <div class="six columns">
      <label for="countryInput">Country</label>
      <select class="u-full-width" id="countryInput">
      <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select the Country</option>
      <c:forEach var="country" items="${countries}" >
        <option id="countryID" value="${country.id}">${country.name}</option>
        </c:forEach>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="six columns">
      <label for="citynameInput">City Name</label>
      <input class="u-full-width" type="text" placeholder="City Name" id="citynameInput" name="city"  value="${company.city}">
    </div>
    <div class="six columns">
      <label for="sizeInput">Size</label>
      <select class="u-full-width" id="sizeInput">
      <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select the Company Size (No. of employees)</option>
        <c:forEach var="companySize" items="${companySize}">
        <option value="${companySize.id}">${companySize.value}</option>
         </c:forEach>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="row">
    <div class="six columns">
      <label for="websiteInput">Website</label>
      <input class="u-full-width" type="text" placeholder="Website" id="websiteInput" name="website" value="${company.website}">
    </div>
    <div class="six columns">
      <label for="countryInput">Industry</label>
      <select class="u-full-width" id="industryInput">
      <option   disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select the Company Industry</option>
        <c:forEach var="industry" items="${industry}">
        <option value="${industry.id}">${industry.industryName}</option>
         </c:forEach>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <label for="aboutus">About Us</label>
  <textarea class="u-full-width" placeholder="About Us" id="about"  name="about" value="${company.about}"></textarea>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="one columns">
      <input class="u-full-width" type="text" placeholder="company Industry" id="companyIndustry" name="industryid"  value="${company.industryid}">
    </div>

    <div class="one columns">
      <input class="u-full-width" type="text" placeholder="company Location" id="companyLocation" name="location"  value="${company.location}">
    </div>

    <div class="one columns">
      <input class="u-full-width" type="text" placeholder="company Size" id="companySize" name="numbere"  value="${company.numbere}">
    </div>
  </div>

  <input class="button-primary" type="submit" value="SAVE">
   <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
</form>
```

Somebody can help please
PS: The Problem is not the Company or User table/Entity. It is how to update a new Record :D

Comment: `CrudRepository.save()` is designed to save **or update**. But for updating the entity, the id of the entity (`Company`) has to be valued as it is passed to the `save(Company)` method. You should give more details about the error you get.

Comment: Hey @davidxxx i don't pass any value to the Save Company. I have this Error could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [uk_ilwhlibdc8eu4ef90ha7f7eh1]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement because Company  has a userid as Foreign key. that is reference by another Table User

Comment: I have a Entity User with the Email and ID and password  for each Users. and i have Entity Company with the Information for each Company. There is onetoone Relationship between Company and User. So Company Table has userid as Foreign key. That is so because i want to save or update the Table Company for each user ID in the Table USER.

Comment: Okay. You should edit your question with the whole stacktrace and the Company class declaration as it makes main part of  the problem. You said that a company is associated to a only one user ??? Are you sure of your model ?

Comment: Yes. The Company Is associated with the Table User. The Id for User table is Foreign Key in Company. When a User register, i save his Email, ID  and Password in a table User. When the User Login, it must Insert new Information about him like Company Name, company Location. I save the Company with the UserID too. to identified for which user is this Company Data. you can create a account hier https://jobfind-master.herokuapp.com/ to unterstand what i means. That is the App

Comment: @davidxxx That is my Github Project App URL https://github.com/allipierre/Jobfind2. Thanks for your help

Comment: @allipierreyotti I have a similar problem how did you solve this problem.